# HTML 5 Video IE9 not loading properly

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-9

I've got this page with 5 separate bio sections. Each one shows text and a video and hides the others. Works in Firefox and Chrome, but not IE9. One video loads in IE9. Whichever one you click on first. The poster disappears right away but the video will play. Clicking on any other name, the video does not pop up.

Link and code to follow. I used the fairly standard method of including video and providing fallback. Anyone have any thoughts?

http://www.friedmanllp.com/experienced_hires_people2.php

```
    <video id="video1" controls="controls" poster="flash/poster_ayanna.jpg" preload="none" width="398" height="224">
        <source src="flash/video_ayanna.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="flash/video_ayanna.mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2" />
        <source src="flash/video_ayanna.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="640" height="360">
            <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['flash%2Fvideo_ayanna.jpg',{'url':'flash%2Fvideo_ayanna.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" />

            <img alt="Ayanna" src="flash/poster_ayanna.jpg" width="398" height="224" title="No video playback capabilities. Please try a different browser." />
        </object>
    </video>
```

Comment: What is happening? Do you see anything at all?

Comment: Well for one... one video loads. Whichever bio you click on first. The poster disappears right away but the video will play. Clicking on any other name, the video does not pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE was throwing it's hands up at the brute force pause all videos.

```
$("#video1")[0].pause();
$("#video2")[0].pause();
$("#video3")[0].pause();
$("#video4")[0].pause();
$("#video5")[0].pause();
```

So I made a check to see if any video elements were playing and paused them accordingly.